# i can't install npm modules from npm why?

Tags: node.js, npm

Whenever I'm using to install some npm modules it shows the same error

For example:
When I type `npm install express` it shows the error like this:-

```
npm ERR! code ERR_OSSL_PEM_NO_START_LINE
npm ERR! error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\mhdra\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-01-14T02_04_52_493Z-debug.log
```

but when I try to clean npm cache using `npm clean cache --force` it shows some error like:-

```
 npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.
```

Comment: Is there more information in the log file the error mentions? And what is your current npm registry (you can check with `npm config get registry`)?

Answer (score 6):

1. try `npm cache clean --force`
2. delete it manually - type in windows search - run - %appdata% - delete npm-cache folder
3. Reinstall node that should fix everything.

Comment: `npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.`

Comment: what about mac?

Comment: You have to find the caches folder.

https://help.ableton.com/hc/en-us/articles/209070509-How-to-access-hidden-folders

Comment: appdata folder in Windows path is C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\npm-cache 
Instead of 1 should be the name of your user

Answer (score 1):

in run dialoge of windows
type  %appdata%
find npm-cache folder
delete it

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
npm install -g npm@latest
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  The question calls for an explanation as to why they cannot do the installation - perhaps you could explain your response - i.e. answer the question in a way that provides an explanation as to why.

Comment: Please consider adding more details about what your command is expected to achieve.

Answer (score -1):

I spent few hours on this error and ended up with below solution. Hope it helps:

Delete files:
%appdata%\npm

Follow these steps

1. npm cache clean --force
2. Uninstall and Install VS code(if it is your code editor)
3. Restart your computer
4. If you have existing repo than delete it and clone it again
5. npm install --force